# Path to home page not working, html

Tags: public-html

How should i arrange my public_html or fix the code so people can click HOME ad go back to the main page without me including each html in the same place as the index.html, i.e, all my inner pages like "reviews" "news" "contact" are al together in along the index.html, and i have read that i shou8ld keep my "reviews" "news" "contact"  on a single foler for each, but it seems my code is not working, what should be the correct code so i dont have to put all the .html files on the same place as index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use base html tag

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/" target="_blank">
</head>

<body>
<img src="stickman.gif" width="24"height="39" alt="Stickman">
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a>
```

http://www.allsolution24.com.bd/webdesign/tutorial/tags/tag_base.html